# Why is plasma used to deposit aluminum on the VLT's four large mirrors?

Tags: observational-astronomy, observatory, instruments, mirror, mirror-making

In Tim Scott's October 2, 2023 video "*The largest telescope that will ever be built**" (note the asterisk, link below) there is a discussion of the "re-silvering" of the four main mirrors of the [Very Large Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_Large_Telescope) (VLT) every 2-3 years when despite regular $\require{mhchem}\ce{CO_2}$ cleaning they accumulate too much dust/dirt:

> They atomise aluminium to create the mirror layer. And when I say atomise, I don't mean like perfume sprayer atomiser. **I mean literally, they use plasma to make individual atoms of aluminium float around in a vacuum**, and then they just let it softly rain down onto the mirror until they have a coating about 1,000 atoms thick.

One common way to deposit thin aluminum films is thermal evaporation - a ceramic alumina ($\require{mhchem}\ce{Al_2O_3}$) crucible containing aluminum metal is heated to a point where the vapor pressure of aluminum results in a flux of atomic aluminum vapor that is emitted at thermal velocity and generally then stick to to whichever surface they hit.

But in this case, at least according to Scott, a plasma deposition process is used.

**Question:** Why is plasma used to deposit aluminum on the VLT's four large mirrors?

I've in fact never heard of plasma deposition of aluminum. I've done a lot of [Plasma-enhanced chemical vapor deposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma-enhanced_chemical_vapor_deposition) for dielectrics (e.g. $\ce{Si_3N_4}$, $\ce{SiO_2}$) and PECVD [diamond-like carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-like_carbon) or DLC is quite popular, but plasma deposition of layers of pure metal is new to me.

So any details about the mechanism will be appreciated!

---

cued at 11:07, just before the block quote begins:

---

Somewhat related:

- [When did "resilvering" large telescope mirrors actually refer to aluminization, and why was it necessary?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16583/7982)
- [Was the use of silver on 'optical' telescope mirrors more common in the past? Why?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16547/7982)

Comment: Sputtering with argon is a good guess. Standard semiconductor processing step.

Comment: @JonCuster Ah, (e.g. argon) plasma sputtering of aluminum, not aluminum plasma, ya I think you've nailed it. I'll bet googling *something like* "sputtering VLT" will get you the supporting source for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [an ESO image](https://www.eso.org/public/images/eso9711d/), the mirrors are coated in a giant [plasma sputter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputter_deposition) system, where ions produced in a (presumably argon) plasma are accelerated and strike the pure aluminum, freeing neutral aluminum atoms which then reach the miror surface and (usually) stick.

It has a diameter of more than 9 meters and a volume of 122,000 liters, pumped with 8 large cryopumps. During deposition the mirror is spun at a stately 5 revolutions per hour under the sputter gun array.